# Android app - saving/storing images at runtime

Tags: java, android, xml, storage

I am learning to build an android app for the first time...this is an educational project.

I don't have a database, and I'm not using a cloud server. The latter is slightly outside of the project scope, and I was advised that I was better using XML to store data, rather than SQLite.

My app should enable users to select images from their image gallery at runtime, these are then resized, and stored in the app (visually - it will look like a pin board of thumbnails). I was going to store them in the resources folder, but have just realised from reading other posts, that this isn't accessible at runtime.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what my options are when I'm not using a cloud server.

Is XML feasible? If so, how do I go about storing images in XML at runtime?

Can I make use of the SD card?

Or is SQLite the only option?

Is there any info where I can read about the limitations and benefits of each of these?

Any advice would be so much appreciated!!

Comment: What about just storing the image as a jpg file in the local app data directory

Comment: @k3b Thanks so much for responding! I have no idea what this is, but it sounds like it might be what I'm looking for. Is there anywhere I can read about it? I know this is probably a 'how long is a piece of string' kind of question, but what about size and max capacity?

Comment: Is this what I should be looking at? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 0):

Realm is better for you. Look at the below links you will get Idea to use realm in your project

https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/

Comment: I don't know if learning something new is a good idea when I have a close deadline. Would you suggest SQLite if I couldn't use Realm? I don't really understand about xml storage for images, or how to do that

Comment: If you are familiar in Core  Java Realm will be easy to learn. If you feel this tough try to use SQLite. It will be better for you. @javapalava

Comment: Thanks @MathaN And would you advise against XML? Is there anywhere that you know that I can read about it?